# Token mismatch exception Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, form-data

I'm uploading a image using laravel and ajax. Following is my html code:

```
<form id='uploadImageForm' class='uploadImageForm'><div class='form-actions noborder'><input type='file' class='file' name='file' attr='file'><input type='hidden' class='productVariantId' name='productVariantId' value='21'><input type='hidden' value='{{ Session::token() }}' class='_token' name='_token'><input type='submit' class='btn default' value='Upload'><label for='multiple' class='control-label'>Add Product Variant Images</label></div></form><br>
```

this is my ajax request code:

```
 $(document).on('submit', '.uploadImageForm', function (event) {

              event.preventDefault();
              var data = new FormData(this);
              for (var value of data.values()) {
                console.log(value); 

              }

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", "{{ route('productVariantImages.add') }}");
            request.send(data);



            });
```

Currently after sending formData object to laravel route the token variable is visible in the network section of browser. following is the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `csrf_token()` instead of `Session::token()`.

See [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf) for details.

Comment: the token is available in screen shot above.It seems like issue is something else

Comment: The value of `csrf_token()` is different with `Session::token()`, have you try to add it to the ajax header like:

`$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`